# Duplicating users if clicking multiple times in ASP.NET (webforms) / OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, owin

I'm creating a user using OWIN. Problem is, while creating an account... I manually check in my database if the user already exists. What is happening quite frequently is, if a user double, triple, or even more clicks it displays them with the "your account has already been made" error, and doesn't automatically redirect them. Furthermore, it creates loads of duplicates of the data I'm saving to another table in SQL which is used for new users signing up.

This is the code that gets executed when the user clicks

```
 if (!u.userExists(email))
   {
   var created = um.CreateUser(email, email, password, firstName, lastName, country, ip);

   if (created == true)
     {
       u.subscribeSIB(email, firstName, lastName, country);
       Response.RedirectPermanent("/members/");
     }
     else
     {
      ipTop.Text = "<span class=\"text-danger mt-3\">An Error Occured</span>";
     }
       }
      else // acc exists
      {
      ipTop.Text = "<span class=\"text-danger mt-3\">Sorry - it seems you've already made an account before. <a href=\"/login\">Sign In</a>.</span>";
      }
```

And this is the code that checks if the user exists

```
    public bool userExists(string email)
   {
    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
    var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
    var useremail = userManager.FindByEmail(email);

    if (useremail == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
```

How should I go about stopping the duplicates, and the multiple triggering?

Comment: you have to make two levels of check. One check with javascript to avoid double clicks, second level on the code behind using mutex to block double submissions

Comment: I fail to see how that routine that creates anew account would be a problem. I mean if the account already exists, why not just re-direct to the logon page then? Additional clicks really should not matter, and the user will be directed to a new page.  I suppose you could in the OnClientClick event go OnClientClick($('#myBtton').hide(); Thus when they click once, the button will hide until such time the page is processed by the server, and thus multiple clicks can't happen. But the real problem is why stay on that page if they already exist? Send them off to logon or whatever.

Comment: @Aristos, how can that be done with asp.net toolbox buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Click Here" OnClientClick="$('.button').hide();" OnClick="MyButton_Click" />
```

You can do the above, using jquery. The OnClientClick will hide the button on the client side, and then the postback will proceed to the server.